# Pandas: Re-indexing after picking those that meet a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to learn more about re-indexing.

For background context, I have a data frame called *sleep_cycle*.
In this data frame, the columns are: Name, Age, Average sleep time.

I want to pick out only those who's names begin with the letter 'B'.
I then want to re-index these 'B' people, so that I have a new data frame that has the same columns, but only has those who's name begins with B.

Here was my attempt to do it:

```
    info = list(sleep_cycle.columns) #this is just to set a list of the existing columns
    b_names = [name for name in sleep_cycle['name'] if name[0] == 'B']

    b_sleep_cycle = sleep_cycle.reindex(b_names, columns = info) #re-index with the 'B' people, and set columns to the list I saved earlier.
```

Results: Re-indexing was succesful, managed to pick those who only began with the letter 'B', and the columns remained the same. Great! Problem was: All the data has been replaced with NaN.

Can someone help me with this one? What am I doing wrong? It would be best appreciated if you could suggest a solution that is only in one line of code.

Comment: Please include a [MRE] with a short example dataframe and your expected output.

Comment: Your question seems to be about conditional filtering of rows, not reindexing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description (example data and expected output would be better), this would work:

```
sleep_cycle[sleep_cycle['name'].str.startswith['B']]
```